# Запрос к MySQL за период, с разбивкой по дням

Tags: php, mysql

Как выбрать в массиве и опубликовать данные за месяц из базы с разбивкой данных за каждый день?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы себе представляете разбивку? База **всегда** возвращает поток строк одинаковой структуры, двухуровневая структура не предусмотрена. База может агрегировать ваши данные за месяц в одну строку, но в этом случае нужно уточнение, что именно вам нужно агрегировать.

Comment: Количество строк в базе с датой к примеру 20070106 и с значением l в поле lead

Answer (score 0):

Следующий запрос выведет агрегацию количества искомых записей по дням

```
SELECT DATE(dt), COUNT(i) FROM leads WHERE lead = 'l' GROUP BY DATE(dt)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5617d/2

Запрос выполнит агрегацию над записями, у которых в поле `lead` значение `l`, посчитав (функция `COUNT`) количество таких записей для каждого дня (`DATE(dt)`). Возможно, есть и более оптимальные решения, но скорее всего и этот запрос у вас выполнится менее, чем за 100мс.

Дополнительные условия можно указать с помощью оператора `HAVING`, который работает схожим с `WHERE` образом, но оперирует над агрегированными данными.

Пожалуйста, в следующий раз оформляйте вопрос так, чтобы из него можно было понять, что вы вообще хотите. Сейчас этого нет.

Comment: Спасибо! Доп вопрос, таких таблиц с разными названия 4 каким образом сделать запрос ко всем сразу?

Comment: @ivanov это вопрос из разряда "как перевезти четыре семьи в Москву". Я не знаю ваших семей, что у них с документами, где они сейчас, и где они территориально должны оказатсья в Москве.